# g++: fatal error: cannot execute 'as': CreateProcess: No such file or directory compilation terminated

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

Hello, I'm trying to learn c++, having installed VStudio Code and MinGW, I was ready to get started but when I try to run the code it says this error:
g++: fatal error: cannot execute 'as': CreateProcess: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

I tried searching for answers to this error but I so far no luck. What can I do to fix this error? what is causing this error?

Comment: `as` is the Linux assembler. Since you are trying to learn C++ and not assembler that suggests something is wrong. What's the full name of the file containing the code you are trying to run?

Comment: BTW If you continue to have problems I suggest you use a compiler that is easier to set up than VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install MinGW's binutils before you use any compiler of GCC, try to find out it in the MinGW get program.